# Maximization of $\sum_{\mathbf{c}_m} \prod_k \left[ (1-p_{k})^{N} p_{k}^{c_{mk}} \right]$

Tags: probability, derivatives, optimization, maxima-minima, maximum-likelihood

Given a matrix $\mathbf{C}$ ($M \times K$) that contains $M$ vectors of $K$ non-negative integers, I have the following probability distribution.

\begin{align}
\sum_{\mathbf{c}_m}
\prod_k
\left[
(1-p_{k})^{N}
p_{k}^{c_{mk}}
\right]
\end{align}

I would like to:

- Maximize it with respect to $\mathbf{p}=(p_1,...,p_k)$ when $\mathbf{C}$ has this kind of structure (note that every $\mathbf{c}_m$ sums up to the same number)

> ```
>        [k1] [k2]
> [m1,]    0    3
> [m2,]    1    2
> [m3,]    1    2
> [m4,]    2    1
> [m5,]    2    1
> [m6,]    3    0
> ```

I derivate with respect to $p_k$ and equal to zero and I obtain:

\begin{align}
N\frac{p_k}{1-p_k}
=
\frac
{\sum_{\mathbf{c}_m}
c_{mk}\prod_{k} p_{k}^{c_{mk}}
}
{{\sum_{\mathbf{c}_m}}
\prod_{k} p_{k}^{c_{mk}}
}
\end{align}

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: If I understood it right, isn't it enough to consider only $M=1$?

Comment: Exactly, actually it is the fact that $M>1$ what makes it hard.

Comment: Oh, I should maximize it with respect to $p_i$.